# Facebook share comment to wall

Tags: html, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to make a share comment link with the caption and comment predefined via post, but I am getting stuck just trying to post a static caption.
How do I POST the caption and the correct page to share?

error:

```
Inferred Property   The 'og:url' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Inferred Property   The 'og:title' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
```

from:

```
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Ftpccommedia.com%2Ffb_progs%2Fredir.php%3Fp%3Dshare
```

code:

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=1392552050964797&display=popup&caption=http://tpccommedia.com/fb_progs/redir.php?p=share">Share This App!</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My url did not match the api. meta tag and api url must match.